# blackberry command line app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to write an app that prompts some questions, takes the input and gives back a result. Given that UI design is quite time consuming I would like to write a "command line app" without an UI. My app should work like this:

```
Enter first number:
> 1
Enter second number:
> 3
Result is: 4
```

Is that possibile? I tried to make an hello world app but when I execute it nothing happens.

```
package mypackage;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;

public class Sample extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample ().enterEventDispatcher();        
    }

    public Sample () {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to develop a *console* app on a Blackberry (or any other smart phone for that matter) device. You are going to need to go the time consuming way and make it into a simple UI application.